# Fixed-point Signed Multiplication in Verilog

Tags: verilog, multiplication, fixed-point

I am designing a signed verilog multiplier which I intend to use multiple times in another module.

My two inputs will be always s4.27 format. 1 bit signed, 4 bits of integer and 27 bits of fraction. My output has to be also in s4.27 format and I have to get the most accurate result out of it.

In C, the following not so perfect code snippet did the job.

```
int32_t mul(int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
 int64_t mul = x;
 mul *= y;
 mul >>= 27;
 return (int32_t) mul;
}
```

In verilog my simple version of code is given below,

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module fixed_multiplier (
i_a,
i_b,
o_p,
clk
);

input clk;
input signed [31:0] i_a;
input signed [31:0] i_b;
output signed [31:0] o_p;
wire signed [63:0] out;

assign out = i_a*i_b;
assign o_p = out;
endmodule
```

The above mentioned code has bugs that I know because I am not getting the desired results at all.

So my questions are,

(1) As this line "assign o_result = out;" seems crucial to me, how shall I do my assignments to my final output so that I get the correct and most accurate s4.27 format output? Please note, this output will be fed to an adder and the adder output will be again an input for the multiplier.

Above question being asked, I also tried with xor-ing of sign bits of both inputs and assigning [57:27] bits to final output. Did not suit me and resulted in overflow, while in C same inputs did not give any overflow error.

(2) With C I did not have any problem with fixed-point multiplication while in verilog I guess I am struggling as I am quite a newbie. Any suggestions what things to keep in mind while dealing with signed multiplication/addition?

Below is the testbench code,

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module tb_mul;
// Inputs
reg clk;
reg [31:0] a;
reg [31:0] b;

// Outputs
wire [31:0] c;

fixed_multiplier mul_i  (
.clk(clk),
.i_a(a),
.i_b(b),
.o_p(c)
);

initial begin

$dumpfile("test_mul.vcd");
$dumpvars(1);

$monitor ("a=%h,\tb=%h,\tc=%h",a,b,c);

  a = 32'h10000000;
  b = 32'h10000000;

  $finish();

end
endmodule
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it supposed to work the same as in your 'c' fragment?  If so, what's wrong in  `assign o_result  = out >> 27;`?

Comment: `[57:27]` would be 31 bits, one bit short of what you need. `assign o_result = out[58:27];` should work.

Comment: @Greg `[57:27]` would be 31 bits thats true.The other bit is x-or of two sign bits from the two inputs. So in total 32 bits.

Comment: @Serge Your suggestion worked better than any other previous solution I had. A big thanks to you.

Comment: `x * y >> 27` truncates, `most accurate result` *may* imply rounding.

Comment: @Serge the problem is that using a logical shift does not keep the signed-ness of the result, it should be `assign o_result = out >>> 27`

Answer (score -1):

Your multiplier does not work like you think it does.  Verilog will assume your multiplication will be unsigned, and will compute it as such.  You might want to do something like the following:

```
wire [61:0] temp_out;
assign temp_out = i_multiplicand[30:0] * i_multiplier[30:0];
assign sign = i_multiplicand[31] ^ i_multiplier[31];
assign out = {sign, temp_out[57:37]};
```

Comment: This method does not seem to return the correct results when outplaying 5.179 with -1 for whatever reason.

Comment: Adding a sign bit to the result doesn't work because signed integers are stored in 2's complement representation